# How to punctuate "No really" correctly

Tags: punctuation

I want to write a sentence such as this.

"No really, that is how it actually works."

I've searched online and found at least 4 different ways people punctuate "no really" in such a sentence:

- No, really. That is ...
- No really, that is ...
- No, really, that is ...
- No. Really. That is ...

Does it matter? And if so which one would be correct?

Comment: Punctuation is often a matter of stylistic choice rather than 'rules'. Personally, I think you need _some_ punctuation after 'no'.

Comment: You need a punctuation mark between "no" and "really". It could be a period, a comma, or a dash.

Comment: This is strictly used in speech, not writing. Hence, punctuation is simply irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

How are you using 'really'?

**1.** With the **exclamatory** addressee-directed pragmatic usage [[Merriam-Webster; adjusted](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/really)]:

> b1 —used to emphasize a [following] assertion [especially a corrective, usually
> showing exasperation]
>
> ...
>
> - *Really, you're being ridiculous!*

- *Oh really? I don't think so!* [[meme, eg on poster](https://keepcalms.com/p/oh-really-i-don-t-think-so/)]

Hence (the comma to show a discontinuity after 'No', optional in the 'Oh really' case, as 'Oh really!' is a fixed phrase):

- "No, really! That is how it actually works."

...................... or ....................

2. With one of the sentence-modifying (traditionally, sentence adverbial) usages [Merriam-Webster; adjusted](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/really):

> a2: in reality : [a deep analysis shows the truth to be]
>
> - *things as they really are*
> - [*the fixed orbit model of the atom is really far too simplistic*]
>
> a3: truly, unquestionably [I kid you not] [a veridical pragmatic usage]

- He looks like an idiot, he talks like an idiot, but don't let this fool you. He *really is* an idiot. [Groucho Marx]
- 36 Jesus himself stood in the midst of them, and said, ‘Peace be with you.’ 37 They were terrified and alarmed, and thought they were seeing a ghost. 38 ‘Why are you so disturbed?’ he said.... 39 Look at my hands and feet; it really is me, myself. Touch me and see! Ghosts don’t have flesh and bones like you can see I have.’ [[Luke 24; NTE; Bible Gateway](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%2024&version=NTE)]

Either of these two usages need the 'really' to be attached to the matrix sentence;

- "No. Really, that is how it actually works."

Usage a3 would be distinguished from a2 in speech by emphasising *really is*.